# Name for a certain universal object in a category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, homological-algebra, universal-property

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and $X$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$ such that for any other object $Y$, there exists a unique epimorphism 
$$
f: X \to Y
$$
and this property identifies $X$ up to unique isomorphism. Do such objects have a name?

Comment: Just a note: The existence of such an object would cause all epimorphisms with a given source to be unique, as for every two epimorphisms $h_1, h_2 \colon Y → Y'$ in $\mathcal C$ and the unique epimorphisms $f_Y\colon X → Y$ and $f_{Y'}\colon X → Y'$, by uniqueness $h_1f_Y = f_{Y'} = h_2f_Y$, so $h_1 = h_2$. This in turn implies that all automorphisms are identities and that any two isomorphic objects are so through a unique isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Such an object $X$ is simply an initial object in the wide subcategory of epimorphisms. A category with an initial object $0$ where all morphisms (or even just morphisms with domain $0$) are epic is necessarily a preorder.